# Apparent error in Jost's Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Theorem 13.1.1 in Jost's Partial Differential Equations asserts that if $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then
$$
u(x) = \int_\Omega \log |x-y| f(y)\ dy
$$
is in $C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

But I think there is an error in the proof.  Equation 13.1.7 says that for fixed $x_1$ and $x_2$ there exist a constant $c_3$ and a point $x_3$ on the line connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\left| \frac{x^i_1 - y^i}{|x_1-y|^2}
-
\frac{x^i_2 - y^i}{|x_2-y|^2}
\right|
\leq c_3
\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{|x_3-y|^2}
\end{equation*}

Here, $x_1^i$ refers to the $i^{th}$ component of $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  However, $x_3$ obviously has to depend on $y$.  Otherwise, we could send $y$ to $x_1$ and get the left-hand side of the inequality to blow up, while keeping the right-hand side finite.

But in the next step, Jost splits an integral in $y$ over a domain  $D$ into an integral over $D \setminus B_\delta(x_3)$ and $B_\delta(x_3)$.  I don't see how this works if $x_3$ depends on $y$.

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to be a fatal error.  My questions are:

(1) Is this an error in Jost or am I mistaken?

(2) If it is an error in Jost, is the result still true?  I don't see it in, for instance, Gilbarg and Trudinger.  They have a similar estimate but require Holder continuity for $f$.